# Доступ к элементам массива из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

У меня есть скрипт, в котором объявлен массив спрайтов

```
public Sprite[] cards = new Sprite[11];
```

Как получить доступ к элементам этого массива из другого скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов решения много. Попробую описать два самых простых.

**оффтоп**: *настоятельно советую имена классов и методов начинать с заглавной буквы, в дальнейшем это может помочь избегать путаниц между именами классов и переменных.*

**1. Ищем нужный компонент (класс-потомок `MonoBehavior`)**

Правки только по коду. На момент создания класса `privet` класс `main` должен существовать.

```
public class privet : MonoBehaviour
{
  main mc;
  Sprite temp;

  //Для корректной работы следует обратить внимание на регистр написания имени этого метода
  private void Start()
  {
    mc = FindObjectOfType<main>();
    //если Вы уверены, что класс main находится на том же объекте, что и текущий, то можно так:
    //mc = GetComponent<main>();
  }

  public void newsprites()
  {
    temp = mc.cards[0];
    gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = temp;
  }
}
```

**2. Скрипт (класс) содержит общедоступную переменную**

Этот способ годится только в случае, когда в Редакторе оба компонента расположены на одной сцене/префабе и т.д.

```
public class privet : MonoBehaviour
{
  //Общедоступная переменная, в Редакторе в окне Иерархии перетаскиваем компонент `main` в это поле
  public main mc;

  private Sprite temp;

  public void newsprites()
  {
    if (mc == null)
      return;

    temp = mc.cards[0];
    gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Использовал первый способ, получилось. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

создайте экземпляр класса с массивом в вашем скрипте, например:

```
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.cards[0];
```

Comment: не получилось. Класс, к массиву которого я хочу получить доступ, называется main. использовал следующий код для создания экземпляра : "main mc = new main(); temp = mc.cards[0];" где temp, переменная типа sprite

Comment: проверьте с отладчиком значение `cards[0]`, есть вероятность, что там просто null и из за этого temp тоже становится null-ом

Comment: Этот вариант плох, если `MyClass` наследуется от `MonoBehaviour` - т.к. будет создан новый компонент.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал создать экземпляр класса с массивом, но ничего не вышло.
Скрипт с массивом:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class main : MonoBehaviour
 {    
  public Sprite[] cards = new Sprite[11];
 }
```

Второй скрипт, из которого пытаюсь получить доступ к массиву :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class privet : MonoBehaviour
{
  main mc = new main();
  Sprite temp;
  public void newsprites()
   {
    temp = mc.cards[0];
    gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = temp;
   }
}
```

В результате, вместо того что бы поставить на объект новый спрайт, удаляется уже существующий.

Comment: Написал ответ, попробуйте.